# strange behaviour asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, apk, progressdialog

I've got a class called Download which extends the AsyncTask. 
The OnPreExecute method does the following :

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();   
    this.dialog.setTitle("Check updates...");

    this.dialog.show();

}
```

The dialog listed is instantied in the constructor of the class and has the following charateristics:

```
 dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
 dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

In the doInBackground method I'll do a lot of network operations and I'll call the progress update method every time I'm able to download an image from a desired url :

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onProgressUpdate(values);



    //call the onprogress update
    publishProgress("1000");

    //do a lot of stuff with the network


 }
```

In the onprogressupdate I'll dismiss the first dialog created and I'll show another one:

```
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        if(values[0].equals("1000")){

            dialog.dismiss();

                  progress_brand.show();

            progress_brand.setProgress(progress_brand.getProgress()+1);

            if(progress_brand.getProgress() == progress_brand.getMax()){

                progress_brand.dismiss();

            }

        } 
 }
```

So basically : at the start of the asynctask I'm showing a dialog with a title "check updates" ... then I'll search for those updates in the doinbackground method and if I'll find some, I'll use the publish progress to dismiss the "old dialog" and create a new one with the ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL. This last dialog is updated everytime I'll download something from the net.

So here's the problem. If I'll run the application with eclipse and then during a download I'll pause the application everything works fine. If I re-enter the application in a second time I can see that the download continues perfectly and I can see the second progress bar continuing to update itself as expected.

If however I make a signed apk --> install the application through that apk --> start the app --> put it on pause during a download -->re-enter the app, then the first dialog is showed again and the download can't proceed properly. 
I've seen from the logcat that if I'll run the app from eclipse the onpreexecute method is called only once, even if I'll exit and re-enter in the app.
However if I'll install the app through the apk the onpreexecute method is called everytime I'll exit and then re-start the app.

Why is that happening? I've tried to clean the project and other basic operations to see if the problem was the creation of that apk, but with no results.

Comment: You may want to show(or explain) how/from where you start that download task.

Comment: Remember, every time you re-enter to the app, that activity will be created therefor onResume method will be called, where did you put your asyncktask.start method?.

Comment: I'm starting the download task from the main activity of the project (in the oncreate method):                                                                 if(isOnline()){
  final Download d = new Download(this, this.getApplicationContext());
  d.execute("");
  }

Comment: the onresume method gets correctly called, however if I'll install the app from eclipse, even if i'll exit and re-enter in the app, the download continue with no problem at all. If however I make an apk and try to do the same thing....boom!

Answer (score 0):

no, you do not use ProgressDialog in your AnyTask

try this (for example)

```
public class Updated extends Activity {
    /**
     * ProgressDialog which is shown
     */
    private ProgressDialog progessDialog_g;
    private boolean downloadUses = false;


    /**
     * Instance of the BroadcastReceiver
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver_g;
    private IntentFilter iFilter;
    protected ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }

    };
    private Intent sI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.progress);

        progessDialog_g = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // Reads and sets the settings for the ProgressDialog

        // Create the IntentFilter for the different broadcast messages
        iFilter = new IntentFilter(
                ProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH);
        // Creates the BroadcastReceiver
        receiver_g = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                if (ProgressService.PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH
                        .equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    // Finishs the ProgressDialog
                    progessDialog_g.cancel();
                    Finish();

                }
            }
        };




    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        sI = new Intent(this, ProgressService.class);
        this.bindService(sI, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        this.startService(sI);
        // Registers the BroadcastReceiver
        registerReceiver(receiver_g, iFilter);
        if (downloadUses) {
            downloadUses = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {

            progessDialog_g.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progessDialog_g.setMessage("you messege");
            progessDialog_g.show();

            new DownloadJSONTask(this, sI)
                    .execute(Initialize.server_url+"/changes/update/1");

        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        this.stopService(new Intent(this, ProgressService.class));
        this.unbindService(mServerConn);
        unregisterReceiver(receiver_g);
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void Finish() {

        Intent in = new Intent(this, RegionsActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        downloadUses = true;
    }

}

}
```

and

```
public class ProgressService extends IntentService {

    public static final String PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH = "Dialog.Progress.MyKey.Finish";

    public ProgressService() {
        super("ExampleProgressService");
    }

    /**
     * Send the finish message.
     */
    private void closeProgressActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PROGRESS_DIALOG_BROADCAST_FINISH);

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // extractVariablesFromIntentAndPrepare(intent);

        String action = intent.getStringExtra("Action");

        if ("0".equals(action)) {

            closeProgressActivity();

        }

    }

}
```

and in you AnyTask

```
sI.putExtra("Action", "0");
        context.startService(sI);
```

and in you manifest

```
  <service android:name=".Intent.ProgressService" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please provide me more details about this solution? I can't understand it